# Multiple value as key in Map Collection

Tags: java, sql, dictionary

**Problem:** I am storing the SQL statements of a table in a map as PK value of the table maps to the corresponding insert/select statement. But now i came across a table which uses **composite Key(4 Pk )**.

Now the base of my logic is shaken as far as i read a array cannot be used as Key in any Map is there is any way i can over come this ?

I am declaring the map as below

```
Map<String, String> pkMap= new Map<String, String>();
```

where the key is the primary key of the table .

**Note:** I am processing few tables in the DB not all of them have 4 PK as composite key few may have only 2 or 1

Comment: Create an immutable class holding the four attributes and use it as the key type in your map. Don't forget to override `hashcode` and `equals`.

Comment: @jlordo yes but not all the tables have 4 pk's few may make composite key with just 2pk's so it is not static the count of pk's

Comment: Then you can use a `List` or an array. Just be sure to make it immutable and override `equals` and `hashcode`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply use a `List<String>` as the key (or even a `List<Object>` if you want to support heterogeneous types). Two lists are equal if they have the same size and if all their members are equal.

Answer (score 0):

How about defining a key class:

```
class DBKeys {
 private List<String> keys = new ArrayList<String>;

 public void addKeyToList(String key) {
     keys.add(key);
 }

  public List<String> getKeys() {
      return keys;
 }

 // override hashcode and equals as well
}
```

then define your map as

```
 Map<DBKeys,String> = new HashMap<DBKeys,String>
```